# How to close pinned tab at firefox using Vimperator

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

I am trying to close the [pinned tab](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open) in Firefox 27.0.1 using Vimperator 3.8.2 using the <kbd>d</kbd> key, such as Gmail pinned tab on the picture above

[image]

but I receive the following message:

```
cannot close an app tab. Use :tabclose!
```

used **:tabclose** but still the same message.

Comment: Are you looking for a shortcut to unpin it?  The whole point of pinned tabs is that they never close.

Comment: But sometimes we need to close muliple pinned tabs. That is how life is. And when we wan to, life gets very tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `:tabclose!` includes an exclamation mark.  Exclamation marks are commonly used in vim to perform an operation defeating safety mechanisms, for example `w!` will write over a write-protected file, first removing the readonly attribute.  And `q!` will quit discarding unsaved changes.

Comment: Oh. So that exclamation mark is actually part of the command. Thanks heaps.